# Decode Raw Data in Zapier

Tags: javascript, node.js, slack, slack-api, zapier

I'm using Zapier's webhooks function to receive data coming from slack.
I have a slack bot set up, using botkit, to send Zapier documents uploaded in chat via webhooks.
Here's the code:

```
controller.on('file_share', function(bot, message) {
  var url = message.file.url_private;

  var opts = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: url,
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + bot.config.bot.token,
    }
  };

  request(opts, function(err, res, body) {
    console.log('FILE RETRIEVE STATUS', res.statusCode);
  }).pipe(request.post(webhook));
```

My problem is that Zapier can't catch the webhook normally, so I have to settle for catching the raw data. Is there a way, in Zapier, to convert the raw data back to its original format? Right now I'm trying to send a jpeg to zapier, so  zapier can send it to google drive.

EDIT:
I'm pretty sure I can use the code:

```
var http = require('http'),
fs = require('fs');

http.get(inputData, function(res) {
  res.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('doc.jpeg'));
});
output = {id: 1};
```

to create recreate the jpeg file I was after, but I'm not sure how to include the jpeg file as an output that Zapier can use.

Answer (score 0):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

As a general rule of thumb, Zapier is best with images when they're a url, not an image file itself. That said, what format you need depends on what else you're trying to do with the image.

Either way, I'd recommend uploading the image to [imgur](https://api.imgur.com/endpoints/image/) (or another web host) and then passing the resulting image url around.

​Let me know if you've got any other questions!